# Prototype Overlay Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, scope, overlay, prototypejs

I have the following code in a file called overlay.js:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    emailSignUp();
});

function emailSignUp() {
    var x = new Overlay();
    x.show('<div class="popup"><div class="close">[ <a href="#" onclick="x.hide(); return false;">Close Window</a> ]</div></div>', {
        position: 'center',
        modal: true,
        animate: true,
        auto_hide: false,
        click_hide: false,
        opacity: 1,
        bckg_opacity: 0.7 }
    );
}
```

It uses prototype 1.6.1 and the following overlay library: http://kammerer.boo.pl/code/prototype-overlay/

Basically, when clicking the "close" link inside the popup, the popup does not close and I get `x` is not defined, which makes sense.

I tried instantiating `x` outside of the `emailSignUp` function, passing it in, and returning it, but that also didn't work.

I've never worked with prototype before, so I'm trying to find the best possible way to make the `hide` function work.

When calling `hide` right after `show`:

```
function emailSignUp() {
    var x = new Overlay();
    x.show('<div class="popup"><div class="close">[ <a href="#" onclick="x.hide(); return false;">Close Window</a> ]</div></div>', {
        position: 'center',
        modal: true,
        animate: true,
        auto_hide: false,
        click_hide: false,
        opacity: 1,
        bckg_opacity: 0.7 }
    );
    x.hide();
}
```

It works with no problems.

Any help is much appreciated!

-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the event listener function in the same scope and bind it:

```
function emailSignUp() {
    var x = new Overlay(),
    linkId = "link-"+(+new Date); //Gives something like "link-1319732520379"

    x.show('<div class="popup"><div class="close">[ <a href="#" id="'+linkId+'">Close Window</a> ]</div></div>', {
    position: 'center',
    modal: true,
    animate: true,
    auto_hide: false,
    click_hide: false,
    opacity: 1,
    bckg_opacity: 0.7 }
    );

    Event.observe( document.getElementById( linkId ), "click",
        function(){
        x.hide(); //x is known here
        return false;
        }
    );
}
```

Note: I have not ever used prototype which is why I am using `document.getElementById`